# Self hosted WCF SOAP Cors preflight

Tags: wcf, soap, cors

How to handle Cors preflight in self hosted WCF soap service? Most examples I have seen are related to WCF Rest or IIS hosted or simple Cors.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that your luking for an answer of .NET solution, on the other hand, this might be giving an idea of solution for you.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html

Here in SOAPHandler section, when it is an "OutBoundMessage", then you should add CORS headers to avoid getting security error from browser.